# javascript xmlhttprequest synchronous onerror

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, работает-ли событие onerror в синхронном запросе. Спасибо.

Мой код:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET',"/customer/"+login,false);
xhr.onerror = function(){
    alert("XMLHttpRequest error");
    console.log("XMLHttpRequest error");
    authorizedCustomer = new Customer("Username","Password");
    authorizedCustomer.authorities = [{"name":"ROLE_ADMIN"}];
    alert(JSON.stringify(authorizedCustomer));
    return;
}
xhr.send();
authorizedCustomer = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

но, при работе в фоновом режиме (без связи с сервером) код ошибки не отрабатывает.

Comment: в каком браузере ты пробуешь?

Comment: судя [по спецификации](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) браузеры сейчас должны исключение кидать при использовании синхронных запросов не в webwoker. А если посмотреть [на обработку ошибок](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#handle-errors), то при синхронном запросе должно быть исключение.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получать коды ошибок в XMLHttpRequest я использую вот такой код

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
var readyStateChange = function () {
                if (xhr && xhr.readyState == 4) {
                  var status = xhr.status; // статус-код запроса, 200-все хорошо, 404-страница не найдена
                  var result = xhr.responseText; // результат запроса
                  // здесь что-то делаешь
                }
            };
xhr.onreadystatechange = readyStateChange;
xhr.send();
```

Comment: плохой код, так как нет самой проверки статуса

Comment: Меня интересует именно функция onerror она что в синхронном запросе не работает?

Comment: в синхронном запросе статус можно проверить после send(); if(xhr.status == 200)

Comment: Это я знаю, я, наверное, не совсем понятно изложил вопрос...Мне нужно, что бы код срабатывал не при ошибке, а при exception. Т.е. если send выдает такой (Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load) exception делать return, а скрипт продолжается дальше....Идея в том, что тут обязательно надо синхронным запросом это делать. В асинхронном я его перехватываю xhr.onerror...